# What is a good free online poll/survey app?

Tags: php, mysql, survey

I need to conduct a survey of 3 questions:

- The first question will be Yes/No.
- The second will have multiple answers, in which you can select multiple answers for just that question, as well as an "other" box that you can use to fill in an answer.
- The last question will be a textarea in which the user can enter general comments/suggestions.

I would love for this survey app to have an administration end so I can export results to a standard format and/or be able to view the stats via the interface.

One I did find was [this](http://www.limesurvey.org/). Are there any others like this?

EDIT: PHP/MySQL based.

Comment: Accepted answer has broken link. Check https://fastpoll.me 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.google.com Create a form and collect results of the survey in spreadsheet

Answer (score 3):

I looked into this a few years ago.  Surveymonkey is a web service that appears to be widely used, especially by non-computer literate.  If you want to modify, serve and count yourself (possible for free), see [this comparison chart](http://websurveytoolbox.org/FeatureTable.html).

Answer (score 2):

I use [eSurv.org](http://eSurv.org) because it doesn't cost anything and there are lots of cool options for customizing your survey. I put our school logo on ours.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.surveymonkey.com works well in my experience.